# How to make a JUnit test that does the same test on many values in a list?

Tags: java, junit

I have a JUnit test with one @Test method that does the same test on a long list of values.

When I run the "tests" there's just one green check mark JUnit test success (in the Eclipse UI).

How can I tweak this so each value test appears as a separate JUnit test in the UI so I can more easily locate which one fails?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class MyBigTest {

@Test
public void testAllValues() {
   List<String> allValues = new ArrayList<String>();
   allValues.add("value1");
   allValues.add("value2");
   allValues.add("value3");
   allValues.add("value4");
   allValues.add("value5");

   for (String value : allValues) {
      String something1 = doSomethingToValue(value1);
      if (something1 == BAD) {
         throw Exception("bad "+value);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is JUnit's ParameterizedTest.  I do not have the time to prepare a formal answer but the breadcrumb may be enough to get your going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are still using JUnit 4 (because you annotated your class with `@RunWith()`.)

With JUnit 4 writing parameterized tests for Spring applications is fairly complex because you can have only one TestRunner and for parameterized tests you need to use the [`Parameterized`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Parameterized-tests) runner. And that means that setting up the Spring application cannot be done automatically by using the `SpringRunner`.

https://www.baeldung.com/springjunit4classrunner-parameterized has a detailed example how you can achieve this.

---

The whole thing would be a lot easier if you could switch your test to JUnit 5 because JUnit 5 has better support for [parameterized tests](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests):

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class MyBigTest {

@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(strings = {"value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5"})
public void testAllValues(String value) {

    String something1 = doSomethingToValue(value);
    if (something1 == BAD) {
        throw Exception("bad "+value);
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need to migrate all your tests to JUnit 5 - JUnit 5 can also run JUnit 4 tests.

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks for spotting my JUnit 4 deficiency!